# Matlab load & unzip 2 .gz files

Tags: sql, matlab, gzip

I'm relatively new to Matlab and I'm loading a .gz file and unzipping it to push it into a SQL database.

It calls functions that establish a connection somehow - which works (jd.conn, etc.) but the weird part is that I get:

> Improper index matrix reference

When I hit the loop.

```
    clear; 
    clc; 
    %% Connection 
    run('/C:/connect/connect_to_sql'); 
    load('/C:/connect/configuration.mat'); 
    global configuration 

    filepath = '/home/C:/folder/'; 
    homeDir = cd(filepath); 
    addpath(homeDir); 
    filenames = dir('*.gz'); 

    //LOOP STARTS HERE
    for i = 1:size(filenames,1) 
        filenames = strrep(filenames(i).name, '*.gz', ''); 
        [insert_query, transfer_query] = create_query(filenames);     
        gunzip(filenames(i).name); 
        query(jd.conn, insert_query); 
        query(jd.conn, transfer_query); 
    end 

    cd(homeDir); 
    disp('Reference files loaded.');
```

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: One main problem is you rewrite `filenames` in the first line of your loop. So change that variable. And `strrep` probably doesn't need the asterix if you're trying to remove the extension (also it may not be the best approach if that's your goal).

Comment: The error message is: Improper index matrix reference
What should I change 'filenames' or that line into?

Answer (score 0):

The likely source(s) of error are mentioned in the comments: you immediately overwrite your variable `filenames` and probably have an extra `*` in your `strrep` argument.

Assuming you simply want to remove the file extension from `filenames(i).name` and pass that to `create_query`, you can do it using [`fileparts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) (and store the result in a new variable):

```
for i = 1:size(filenames,1) 
    [~, queryName, ~] = fileparts(filenames(i).name); 
    [insert_query, transfer_query] = create_query(queryName);
    ...
```